# Oracle 11g: How to fetch column type from view?

Tags: sql, oracle11g

On my remote `@ABC.WORLD` database I have only access to view (naturally) and is it possible to fetch column's data types? Like `DESC` or from `USER_TAB_COLS` ?

**EDIT:**
Executing `DESC` will no help:

```
SQL> DESC user123.v_abc@abc.world;
Object user123.v_abc@abc.world does not exist.
```

But executing:

```
SELECT *
  FROM ALL_VIEWS@ABC.WORLD
 WHERE VIEW_NAME = UPPER('v_abc')
   AND OWNER = UPPER('user123');
```

Returns view definition (is select from another user and table).

Comment: desc or describe will work....

Comment: if u know the table use user_tab_columns to view column information

Comment: I can confirm that `desc` works. You have some other issues that broke the command.

Comment: @user272735 Life is life and books are books. So that's way practice is better than knowledge :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the query

```
select * from all_tab_columns@ABC.World where table_name='viewname'
```

Comment: didn't know that `ALL_TAB_COLOLUMNS` contains views also :)

Comment: I approved this answer because `user_tab_columns` hasn't give any rows

Answer (score 1):

OR YOU CAN RUN

```
select column_name,data_type 
    from user_tab_columns@ABC.World
        where table_name='V_ABC'
```

Comment: didn't know that `ALL_TAB_COLOLUMNS` contains views also :)